# How to disable Java Portable Security Warning once for all?

Tags: java, security, configuration

I have jdk1.8.0_111 as portable on my W7 machine.

Every time when I'm launching a Java client and it tries to connect to the JBoss on another machine, Java Security Warning occurs as below, containing the JBoss location:

Java Security Warning

[image]

Question: How to disable it once for all?

File "\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security\exception.sites" already contains the location mentioned on the warning screen but apparently does not work.

Comment: Are you trying to hide the pop-up notification only for this specific website, or in general?

Comment: For two specific websites. This one is an example.

Comment: Have a look at this. Seems to work with Firefox http://gdgtry.com/2010/05/disable-javas-new-security-warning/ I have not tested it, as I am not using Java on the browser.

Comment: How can I run the Java Control Panel having Java portable version?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the security warning came from https://fqdn/somejar.jar file.  The website being accessed had valid certificate - however the jar application file has a code signing certificate.

It was beyond annoying and it took me a while to finally address the issue.

**Warning:** GPO update solution affects multiple systems.  Take caution and avoid Resume Updating Event.

[image: Details on Java Security Wardning (More Information Link)]

The following helped me address the issue:
On windows side, after searching on Java and Stackoverflow site, I found there are two directories:

**User specific:** C:\users\%username%\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security\

**System shared**: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jrex.x.x_xxx\lib\security

On the user specific directory, I updated trusted.cacerts, trusted.jssecacerts and trusted.certs to have the certificate utilized by the JAR file.

To find details about the codesiging certificate, we can use javasigner.exe from command line.  For example, in my case, I download the *.jar file and run the following command:

[image: Command line jarsigner.exe]

Once details about the codesigning certificate is discovered, the next step is validating if the certificate is valid/not revoked and adding it to Trusted Certificates under the Java Control Panel (JCP).
[image: Add CodeSigning Certificate under JCP - Signer CA]

In Active Directory Group Policy maintained environment, this can be applied without the need for touching every PC manually (assuming you are 100% the certificate is NOT revoked or has not expired).  Of-course when doing this via GPO, one needs to test it to make sure the cert stores maintained per user basis are the same and all users have same JRE version. Applied to the **User Configuration** > Preferences > Windows Settings > Files - location.

[image: GPO Updated cert stores - Per Logged in user basis]

Updating the shared system certificate stores can be maintained via GPO too.  I was able to add the Code Signing certificate via command line using Keytool.exe. As you can see, the import option is grayed out on the system tab of JCP. It is possible I am doing it the hard way, however I was not able to do system side of updating the certificate store via the JCP window.

**Command line:** C:> keytool -keystore cacerts -importcert -alias yourcertcaname -file downloadedcert.cer

If all goes well, you should see the certificate under the system tab of JCP. 
[image: Importing cert to the cacert file via keytool command]

Just like the user specific certificate stores, the cacert file can be maintained via GPO.  Again, this is assuming you have a good handle on JRE installation in your environment and PCs on your network do not have different certificate store settings. Test, test test test and when done testing, test again.  Applied to **Computer Configuration** > Preferences > Windows Settings > Files location.

Hope this helps someone trying to do away with Java Security Warning windows.

Cheers.